# How can I retrieve date from click event of Kendo Calendar?

Tags: calendar, click, kendo-asp.net-mvc

I have a Kendo calendar with two events onchange and click. onchange event I can get the value of selected date. But I need to get the date when user click on selected date too.

```
<script async src="//jsfiddle.net/Q6ust/96/embed/"></script>

http://jsfiddle.net/Q6ust/96/
```

Comment: @SeanCh, Thanks for your reply.

$("#calendar").on("click", "td.k-state-selected", function(e) {
  alert("Clicked");
});

Here is my event. When user click on a highlighted/selected date it's fire. I need to capture the date here.

Hope it's now more clearer.

Comment: I am not very fluent in English. Sorry. :( 

If you got some seconds and check the fiddle you'll understand what I am trying to say. Thanks for your time.

Comment: Sorry for late response. It's worked. Thanks,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

working demo link [dojo sample](http://dojo.telerik.com/IzITo).

Please find below the working copy of the code.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Untitled</title>

  <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2017.1.118/styles/kendo.common.min.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2017.1.118/styles/kendo.rtl.min.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2017.1.118/styles/kendo.default.min.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2017.1.118/styles/kendo.mobile.all.min.css">

  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.3.min.js"></script>
  <script src="http://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2017.1.118/js/angular.min.js"></script>
  <script src="http://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2017.1.118/js/jszip.min.js"></script>
  <script src="http://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2017.1.118/js/kendo.all.min.js"></script></head>
<body>

  <h4>Pick a date</h4>
                <div id="calendar"></div>
            </div>
            <div class="box" style="text-align: center;">
                <h4>Events log</h4>
                <div class="console"></div>
            </div>

            <script>
                function onChange() {
                   // console.log("Change :: " + kendo.toString(this.value(), 'd'));
                }

                function onNavigate() {
                   // console.log("Navigate");
                }

                $("#calendar").kendoCalendar({
                    change: onChange,
                    navigate: onNavigate
                });

               $( "#calendar" ).click(function() {             
                 var d = $("#calendar").data("kendoCalendar").value();
                 console.log(d);                 

               });


            </script>


</body>
</html>
```